# stratis file system creation failed bcuz log stripe unit is too large. mkfs.xfs: libxfs_device_zero write failed: no space left on device

Tags: linux, filesystems, storage

I am studying for RHCSA with the book by Asghar Ghori. I use virtualbox 7 and RHEL 9 on my macbook. Currently I am in Chapter 14 about Stratis and doing the exercise to create and confirm a pool and file system. But An error occurred and I cannot move forward.

Here are the steps and the error.

1. first confirm the disk availability

```
$ lsblk /dev/sdf
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sdf    8:80   0   1G  0 disk
```

2. create a pool and verify

```
$ sudo stratis pool create bookpool /dev/sdf
$ sudo stratis pool list
Name      Total / Used / Free               Properties    UUID                                  Alerts
bookpool  1 Gib / 5126.82 Mib / 507.18 Mib  ~Ca, ~Cr, Op  7fe605a5-8620-4c65-9cfl-326270784c78  WS001
```

3. display the block device used to form the pool

```
$ sudo stratis blockdev list bookpool
Pool Name   Device Node   Physical Size   Tier
bookpool    /dev/sdf             1 Gib    Data
```

so far so good. But here's the problem.

4. The fourth step should create a file system called *bookfs* in the *bookpool* and return no output. But I got an error instead.

```
$ sudo stratis filesystem create bookpool bookfs
Execution failed:
stratisd failed to perform the operation that you requested. It returned the following information 
via the D-Bus: ERROR: Command failed:  cmd: "/usr/sbin/mkfs.xfs" "-f" "-q" "/dev/dm-7" 
"-m" "uuid=26c8b46b-2a4b-44db-947d-e8fd89268fdc", exit reason: 1 stdout: stderr: log stripe unit 
(1048576 bytes) is too large (maximum is 256KiB) log stripe unit adjusted to 32Kib
mkfs.xfs: libxfs_device_zero write failed: No space left on device.
$
```

I searched the error message but no luck.
Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Increase the block device size as 2GB and proceed as usual
2. Run the filesystem command with `--size` option like the one below

   ```
   sudo stratis filesystem create --size 10GiB pool_name filesystem_name
   ```

Comment: Increasing the device size to 5GB worked. 1 through 4GB didn't work. Thank you.

Comment: I ran into the same, looks like it was a [change in version 3.1 that increased minimum size of volume and metadata volume to 512M](https://stratis-storage.github.io/), which is ~1.05G.  Appears to be related to to a [change in minimum size of xfs](https://github.com/stratis-storage/project/issues/523#issuecomment-1263529186).